# Is there such an iframe available

Tags: html

I built my website using Homestead.  It's a simple site builder.  I recently redid my site to include iframes which works nicely.  Another feature I like to offer my clients is a search engine particular to my industry.  That works just fine. However, the front page search box (which I loaded as html in a code box, when key words are typed, takes you out of my website for the search.  I tried to iframe it, but that didn't work.

Here are the words from one of the techs:  *The problem is it returns and sends you to a link.  When you iframe, there isn’t a way to have a unique link on the site. In your instance, you’ll see the url for the products and product search is always www.adlib.us/productsearch-new.html
The search always needs our page to return products and a correct url for your iframe page, but it only returns one address, so it can’t be put in the address of your iframed page.*

*There may be a way to create a program to handle it, but nothing that we can offer.*

Since he believes it can be done, I was wondering if anyone knew how.

Thanks in advance for your help.  ron

Comment: Sounds like a confusing issue. Are you using a custom search tool? or using something like a google search plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Try WordPress or Joomla instead of using these weird Sitebuilders. They both offer great search engine integrated in their core and are very easy to use and customize. To some extent of course. For further customizations try Drupal. WordPress, Joomla and Drupal are opensource which means that it is free and cost nothing except the time you spent wathcing some basic tutorials on youtube or reading forums.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Google Custom Search is suitable for you.

http://www.google.com/cse/

You can just copy and paste the embedded Google search box to your custom-built site. Plus, you can also see the analytics of your site searches. No need for iframe and stuff like that.